# Why the phrase "of a" is required here?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases, phrase-choice

[Source](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/whoever.asp)

> A word to the wise: *Whomever* is even more **of a** vogue word than *whom*. Many use it indiscriminately to sound cultured, **figuring that no one will know any better.**

What the **of a** has been placed there and what if I remove it will have effect on it?
Also, explain the absolute phrase meaning in the bold part.

Comment: It's at least *credible* (though significantly less common) to use just ***a*** rather than ***of a*** in such contexts, but no article at all would normally be seen as a reliable indication of "non-native speaker". The highlighted phrase adjectivally modifies ***use it*** - it means that (while they are pretentiously using ***whomever***), many people assume/think/figure no-one will know better than them how to use it, so they won't be likely to say anythying if it's being used wrongly (which it often is, obviously).

Comment: @FumbleFingers All righty now. You write: _...figure no-one will know better than them how to use it..._ If it ought to be _better than **they**,_ and _they_ comes naturally, should a speaker then intentionally use _them_ to avoid enraging the plebs? (  :)  )

Comment: @P. E. Dant: I'd really like to say *you know better than **I*** in such matters, but I simply can't bring myself to break the habit of a lifetime (*my* universe is all about "Me, me, me!" :) The only time I'm prepared to stop linguistically objectifying others is when it's ***We*** vs ***They*** in the column headings of a bridge score card - in everything else, it's either ***us*** against ***them*** or it's ***me*** against ***you*** (and I don't care how many of youse there are! :)